# how to tell Jetty which is the default web application

Tags: jetty

so I have a web application deployed on Jetty. Lets say the war file is hello.war. For me to access the web app on my own machine I need to go to `http://127.0.0.1/hello` but I want that web application to "listen" to `http://127.0.0.1` without putting Apache in front of Jetty.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is serve your `hello.war` off of the *root context path*. (A *context path* is the path that is assigned to your web app.  The root context path is the context path `"/"`)

You have a number of ways to accomplish this.

1. Change the name of your war from `hello.war` to `root.war` (this lets the [automatic deployment to know what you want to do](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/automatic-webapp-deployment.html))
2. **or** Change the name of your exploded webapp directory from `${jetty.home}/webapps/hello` to `${jetty.home}/webapps/ROOT` (again, the [automatic deployment will know what to do](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/automatic-webapp-deployment.html) with this special named directory)
3. **or** Setup a [Deployable Descriptor XML File](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html) with a configured `contextPath' that the context based deployment will use.

Example of a Deployable Descriptor XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war">/home/user/code/hello.war</Set>
</Configure>
```